# Adiabatic expansion and energy spreading

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, adiabatic

I think of entropy as energy spatial spreading, but i find that in adiabatic expansion there is energy spreading but entropy does not increase. Is the internal energy decrease a way of energy concentrating to compense the increase volume's energy spreading?

Comment: "Is the internal energy decrease a way of energy concentrating to compensate the increase volume's energy spreading?" Can you explain what you mean? How can a decrease in internal energy result in "energy concentrating"?

Comment: I have no problem understanding that in reversible adiabatic expansion the entropy variation is zero, in terms of:
1) Q = 0 implies delta S = 0 according to Clausius.
2) Identical number of microstates at the beginning and at the end.
3) Identical number of occupied energy levels: Lower occupied energy levels for having less internal energy but closer together for having less volume.
My question is about the interpretation of entropy as dispersion of energy. It seems that this interpretation fails in adiabatic expansion because there is energy spreading with no increase in entropy.

Comment: I did some more research and found this https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/185544/how-can-a-reversible-adiabatic-expansion-not-increase-entropy#:~:text=For%20a%20sufficiently%20slow%20process,the%20number%20of%20quantum%20microstates. The answers basically say what I was trying to say, though perhaps better.

Answer (score 0):

> but i find that in adiabatic expansion there is energy spreading but
> entropy does not increase.

Entropy of the gas depends not only on the volume of the gas but also on the internal energy available to occupy that volume. In the case of a reversible adiabatic expansion there is less internal energy available to occupy the increased volume. That's because, from the first law for a closed system, given $Q=0$,

$$\Delta U=-W$$

Meaning the work done by the gas in expanding results in a decrease in the internal energy occupying the increased volume.

Hope this helps.